# I'm trying to convert these 5 Digit FFXI color codes in our database to the corresponding Hex Color code

Tags: php, colors, binary, hex, decimal

I'm in deep need of help, our database stores the color in a 5 digit (what I assume) to be decimal number. I've tried converting using the PHP:

Here are some other 5 digit codes:

```php
function ffxiLinkshellColorToHex($color) {
    $r = ($color & 0x1F) << 3;
    $g = (($color >> 5) & 0x1F) << 3;
    $b = (($color >> 10) & 0x1F) << 3;
  
    $hexR = str_pad(dechex($r), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $hexG = str_pad(dechex($g), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $hexB = str_pad(dechex($b), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  
    return "#{$hexR}{$hexG}{$hexB}";
  }

echo ffxiLinkshellColorToHex(61648); // Should output "#00EF00"
```

But instead it outputs: #8030e0

[image: Example1]

What it should be looking like is this:

[image: Example2]

My brain has almost fizzled out of existence, I feel like the answer is super simple.

Could you please help.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to reproduce your code.  i was checking for the conversion but `#00EF00` does not produce decimal 61648 rather it converts to `61184` . Easiest way to convery decimal to hex in php is to use dechex function in php. Please have a look at this code. There seem to be some missing link....

```
<?php 

$decimal = 61184;

function ffxiLinkshellColorToHex($color) {
    // $r = ($color & 0x1F) << 3;
    // $g = (($color >> 5) & 0x1F) << 3;
    // $b = (($color >> 10) & 0x1F) << 3;
  
    // $hexR = str_pad(dechex($r), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // $hexG = str_pad(dechex($g), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // $hexB = str_pad(dechex($b), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  
    // return "#{$hexR}{$hexG}{$hexB}";

    return '#00'.dechex($color);
  }

$color =  ffxiLinkshellColorToHex($decimal); // Should output "#00EF00"

// $color = dechex(61184);
// $color =  '#00EF00';

?>

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        width: 300px; 
        height: 200px; 
        color:white; 
        font-weight: 600;  
        display:flex; 
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 3rem;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top:15rem;
        align-content: center;
        border-radius: 2rem;
    }
</style>

<div class="box" style=" background: <?php echo $color;?>">
    <p><?php echo $color;?></p>
</div>
```

Produced color:
[image]